# DEP acting differently on different servers

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

We have 2 different servers running Windows 2012r2 that are configured the same (as far as I can tell.) On one DEP is turned on and our app is added to the list of exclusions and it works fine. One the second DEP is configured the same way and the app causes a DEP error (even though the exe is in the list to be excluded.)

I also noticed that if I run the app as the administrator it does not cause a DEP error but if I run it as a user it does. Has anyone seen anything like this before?